# Extracting 8 alphanumeric character from a string value

Tags: sql, regex, hive

I am trying to find an alphanumeric 8 character from a string value. For example : If my string is `//SC202646 ABCBUB22XXX` , then it should extract `ABCBUB22` or any value which satisfies the condition that it is of 8 alphanumeric character length.
I am executing it through sql and want to extract it using regex function

Comment: `SC202646` is also alphanumeric of length=8. Why did you ignore it on your output?

Comment: Like this: [`\b\w{8}`](https://regex101.com/r/VvKXcP/1/) or [`(?<=\s)\w{8}`](https://regex101.com/r/VvKXcP/2)

Comment: Because it starts with "//", I am just trying to retrieve alphanumeric. It should not have Not any special character

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to get the result.. It looks a bit complex but it works.

```
select regexp_substr(sub1, '[A-Za-z0-9]{8}', 1)
  from (select regexp_substr('<input the string here >', '[^ ]+', 1, level) sub1 from dual
              connect by level <= REGEXP_COUNT('< input the string here >', '[^ ]+'))
  where regexp_count(sub1,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]')=0 AND regexp_count(sub1,'[a-zA-Z0-9]')>=8;
```

Consider the below example..

Test string is : //SC202646 ABCBUB22XXX ASFD1234 qwer//s aaddf123456

Firstly in the inner query, we are separating each word based on the space. the result of the inner query is

```
select regexp_substr('//SC202646 ABCBUB22XXX ASFD1234 qwer//s aaddf123456 ', '[^ ]+', 1, level) sub1 from dual
     connect by level <= REGEXP_COUNT('//SC202646 ABCBUB22XXX ASFD1234 qwer//s aaddf123456 ', '[^ ]+');
```

Result :

```
//SC202646
ABCBUB22XXX
ASFD1234
qwer//s
aaddf123456
```

And then in the outer query, we are filtering the data such that, it should have only alphanumeric characters and at-least it should contain 8 characters, then displaying first 8 characters.

So final query and output is

```
select regexp_substr(sub1, '[A-Za-z0-9]{8}', 1)
  from (select regexp_substr('//SC202646 ABCBUB22XXX ASFD1234 qwer//s aaddf123456 ', '[^ ]+', 1, level) sub1 from dual
        connect by level <= REGEXP_COUNT('//SC202646 ABCBUB22XXX ASFD1234 qwer//s aaddf123456 ', '[^ ]+'))
 where regexp_count(sub1,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]')=0 AND regexp_count(sub1,'[a-zA-Z0-9]')>=8;
```

Result :

```
ABCBUB22
ASFD1234
aaddf123
```

Comment: Connect by level doesnt work in hive. Is there any alternative for it?